# Войти с помощью php и скачать файл

Tags: php

Создаю парсер на php. Для того чтобы начать парсить мне нужно скачать файл с каталогом. Файл находится в формате YML он же XML. Данный файл [лежит вот на этом сайте.](http://www.2-buy.ru/ymarket.yml) Проблема заключается в том, что для того чтобы скачать файл мне нужно с помощью php ввести логин и пароль. Но как передать данные если даже тойже формы нет?

Натолкните хотя бы в каком направлении копать, читать. Спасибо.

Comment: посмотрите информацию по `curl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос вот так, выложу здесь. Может кому поможет. Скрипт скачивает входит и скачивает файл сохраняя его под именем ymarkettestload.yml

```html
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$username = 'Логин';
$password = 'Пароль';
$url = 'http://www.2-buy.ru/ymarket.yml';
$fp = fopen("ymarkettestload.yml", "w");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.2-buy.ru/ymarket.yml');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/10.00 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.2.0");
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```

так ты авторизуешься через http auth, и дальше уже как скачать файл думаю знаешь

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду копать =)